# NoReverseMatch error when trying to go to a template page

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

When an item is clicked on, it should take the user to a page where there is more information about the item. However, when I click on an item, I get the error: `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'listing' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<name>[^/]+)/\\Z']`.

This line in my HTML template is highlighted on the error page: `<a href="{% url 'listing' i.pk i.name %}">` but I do not know why. The `i.pk` and `i.name` are arguments for a `views.py` function that is called `listing` that returns a page (`listing.html`) that has more info about the item. The url should be in the format `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ID/NAME_OF_ITEM` where `ID` is the actual id of the item and the `NAME_OF_ITEM` is the actual name of the item.

How do I fix this?

index.html: (this page works fine)

```
{% for i in listings %}
    <div class="listing">
        <div class="info-container">
            <div class="top-info">
                <div class="listing-title">
                    <a href="{% url 'listing' i.pk i.name %}">
                        <h4>{{ i.name }}</h4>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="listing-price">
                    <a href="{% url 'listing' i.pk i.name %}">
                        <strong>£{{ i.highest_bid }}</strong>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="listing-description">
                <a href="{% url 'listing' i.pk i.name %}">
                    <p>{{ i.description }}</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

(the rest is for the `listing.html` page) -->

views.py:

```
def listing(request, id, name):
    listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render(request, 'auctions/listing.html', {
        'listings': Listing.objects.all(),
        'listing': listing
    })
```

urls.py:

```
path('<int:id>/<str:name>/', views.listing, name='listing')
```

listing.html: (this is where the error occurs)

```
<main>
    <div class="sing-container">
        <div class="sing-header">
            <h2> {{ listing.name }} </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sing-container">
        <div class="sing-header">
            <h2> {{ listing.name }} </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="sing-content">
            {% if listing.photo_present != None %}
            <div class="sing-img">
                {% if listing.photo_url != None %}
                <div class="img-center">
                    <a href="{% url 'listing' i.id i.name %}">
                        <img src=" {{ i.photo_url }} " alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <div class="img-center">
                    <a href="{% url 'listing' i.id i.name %}">
                        <img src=" media/{{ i.photo_upload }} " alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Try naming the parameters like `{% url 'listing' pk=i.pk name=i.name %}`

Comment: That did not work. I got an error at the `index` page. @0sVoid

Comment: Does `Listing` model have `name` field? Are you sure that you iterate over `listings` not `listing`? Can you rename `listing` (variable that contains single object) to `curr_object` for example to be sure that template context is not overriden by some django automatic mechanisms (basically it's not great idea to name variable the almost same way, even if you use plural and non-plural syntax).

Comment: Yes the `Listing` model has a name field and I am iterating over the correct variable. The problem is not in the `index.html` file it is in the `listing.html` page as that is where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy and pasted the link to the image from the `index.html` page, where there is a loop and `i` is the current listing in the loop. However, on the listing page there is no loop so there is no `i` as it focuses on only one listing.

So the anything that contains `i.SOMETHING` is wrong as the computer does not recognize `i` as there is none. The images are wrapped in links that link to the current page: `{{ url 'listing' i.id i.name }}` and this is what is causing the error.

I removed all of the times that this came up because I no longer need the images to link to the listing page as the user should currently be on the listing page itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% url 'listing' i.id i.name %}
```

In the listing.html page template, there is no `i` variable, so `i.id` and `i.name` resolve to blank strings.  But the url definition for `listing` requires that those values be nonblank, so you get an error.

In the index.html page, those variable references are contained in a `{% for i in listings %}` loop, so the `i` variable properly exists on that page.

But that is not the case in the listing.html page.

Frankly, I wonder why that page tries to show that link at all, because it would just be a link to the page you're already on.

It looks like you created the listing.html page template by copying the index.html page, and just forgot to change some things.